# How can we access a one class object in another class?

Tags: php

I still have not been able to figure this out. How can we access a one class object in another class?

I am using the below code but I am getting and error:

```
class ListofRecord{
        var $db;
    function __construct(){
            $db = global $db;

    }
    function record(){
       $record = $this->db->SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM user order by UID ASC");
       return $record;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to refer to the global `$db` variable first and then use it in a statement. You also have a minor syntax error in your constructor. You forgot to use the `$this` keyword when referring your your `$db` property.

```
function __construct(){
    global $db
    $this->db = $db;
}
```

It also is a better practice not to use global variables and instead pass any variables that you need as parameters to your method call. In this case it is your constructor:

```
function __construct($db){
    $this->db = $db;
}

$list_of_record = ListofRecord($db);
```